# Verificar tamanho das `Sessions` no servidor

Tags: c#, .net

O método a seguir é usado em uma aplicação web form para guardar informações do usuário logado:

```
public Usuario UsuarioLogado
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["Usuario"] != null)
            return (Usuario)Session["Usuario"];
        else
            return null;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["Usuario"] = value;
    }
}
```

No caso uso uma classe pois irá guardar várias informações que serão usadas em várias partes da aplicação.

Qual a melhor forma de criar as `Sessions`?

Usando a classe? Quais os cuidados que devem ser tomados nesta abordagem?

Ou Criando várias `Sessions` individuais?

```
Session["ForcaTrocarSenha"] = usuario.FirstOrDefault().bit_altera_senha;
Session["SenhaAtual"] = usuario.FirstOrDefault().txt_senha.ToString();
Session["Login"] = usuario.FirstOrDefault().txt_login.ToString();
Session["IdUsuario"] = usuario.FirstOrDefault().int_id_usuario.ToString();
```

No meu entendimento o uso excessivo de `Sessions` vai sobrecarregar a memória do servidor!

Como verificar o consumo de memória das `Sessions` de uma aplicação no servidor?

Teria como fazer isto via uma aplicação web form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há problemas em usar objetos na sessão, na verdade é o recomendado. C# é orientado a objetos (lembra?).

O uso de chaves individuais na sessão dependerá dos dados a serem armazenados, ou seja, deve-se fazer uso do bom senso.
Se você tem um objeto com N propriedades e que usará apenas 1 destas propriedades, por qual razão você armazenaria todo o objeto? Nenhuma.
Se você tem um objeto com 10 propriedades e fará uso apenas de 5, não haverá problemas em armazená-las individualmente, mas o 'ideal' seria criar um objeto com apenas estas 5 propriedades e armazená-lo na sessão.

Referente ao tamanho da sessão, isso dependerá da quantidade de memória disponível e da configuração usada.
Lembre-se que há 4 modos de armazenamento da sessão (InProc, StateServer, SQLServer e Custom). Recomendo a leitura: [Session-State Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.140).aspx)

Quanto ao consumo de memória, você pode tentar a seguinte dica: [How to find out size of session in ASP.NET from web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198082/how-to-find-out-size-of-session-in-asp-net-from-web-application#answer-198386)